# GitHub Actions workflow job if condition to only run when triggered from upstream, not forks

Tags: github-actions

I have a workflow that is triggered on pushes and PRs to the `main` branch:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - main
  push:
    branches:
      - main
```

I want the only job in there to be skipped if the workflow was triggered by a fork (making a PR on upstream). What `if` condition should I use?

Comment: You can look at `github.repository` and make sure it matches: `if: github.repository == 'yourorg/yourrepo'`, though it would be cleaner to  just disable forks from being able to trigger workflows.